# Rearrange bootstrap grid into different numbers of columns without code duplications

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a problem with dinamiacally rearranging my div boxes.

I need two version:

mobile (one column beneath each other):

```
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
```

Any other (the middle one slides out from between the two others):

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div>A</div>
<div>C</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8">
<div>B</div>
</div>
```

I can manage this with code duplications and visible/hidden pairs, but is there a solution without these? Especially I don't want code duplications...

Thanks,

edit:

unluckily, I forgot to add there is another complication:

I need several 100% width elements under this whole ABC thing, and height of the B element changes...

This setup shows that the D and the B overlaps. I want to position the D under the B...:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row parent-row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 div-wrap">
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="b">B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
    <div class="d">DDDDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD DDDDD DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
  .b{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    width: 66.66666667%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    min-height:1px;
  }

  .d{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    min-height:1px;
  }


  .div-wrap{
    position:initial;
    clear:both;
  }

  .parent-row{
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this will do the trick for you:
http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/xRqgJe

The important bit is that when the viewport is wider than the stacked mobile view, you use a media query to take div 'B' out of normal flow by applying 'position:absolute'. And at the same time you manually apply the Bootstrap CSS styling for a 'col-lg-8' div, and you also tweak the positioning of its parents (.div-wrap and .parent-row) so that .B floats to the correct position.

Good luck

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row parent-row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 div-wrap">
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
   </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
  .b{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    width: 66.66666667%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    min-height:1px;
  }

  .div-wrap{
    position:initial;
  }

  .parent-row{
    position:relative;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use absolute position. Apply `float: right;` and `clear: left;` properties instead.

I've tested two situations:

1. block A is higher than B
2. block B is higher than A

[image: tests]

Please check the result: http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/dOezEz

```css
/* Heart of the matter */
@media (min-width: 1200px ) {
  .clear-lg-left {
    clear: left;
  }
  .pull-lg-right {
    float: right !important;
  }
}

/* Tests */
.tests {
  margin-top: 14px;
}
.tests > div {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 6px; 
}
.tests > div:nth-of-type(1) { background: #9c6; min-height: 120px; }
.tests > div:nth-of-type(2) { background: #f93; min-height: 80px; }
.tests > div:nth-of-type(3) { background: #69c; min-height: 80px; }
.test-2 > div:nth-of-type(2) { background: #f93; min-height: 160px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row tests">
    <div class="col-lg-4">A</div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 pull-lg-right">B</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 clear-lg-left">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row tests test-2">
    <div class="col-lg-4">A</div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 pull-lg-right">B</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 clear-lg-left">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```